# AEM Editor Page becomes black

Tags: aem-6

I am using AEM 6.5 then suddenly my page become black. How to return it from the original?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Might be something related to the dark mode, you should be able to inspect the page to see where it's coming from.

For more info you can check [this](https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/wknd-tutorial-aem-editor-dark-mode/td-p/401630), might be the same issue.